# Можно ли открыть xlsx в Python используя предоставленные библиотеки

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Можно ли каким либо способом работать с таблицей xlsx на Python, без установки библиотек? Я видел много разных библиотек, но они все "не идут в комплекте".

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: И в чем проблема сделать в комплекте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем изобретать велосипед? Используйте готовые разработки с удовольствием. Но если хотите помучаться, то можно сохранить файл xlsx в файл csv, "сохранить как...", а затем использовать стандартный модуль csv. class csv.Dialect

> class csv.excel
> The excel class defines the usual properties of an Excel-generated CSV file. It is registered with the dialect name 'excel'.

class csv.excel_tab
The excel_tab class defines the usual properties of an Excel-generated TAB-delimited file. It is registered with the dialect name 'excel-tab'.